# Speech to text in WSR

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am actually trying to convert Speech to Text in Windows Speech Recognition but unable to do it.

Actually I am able to Get the focus on to the test box but unable to type in anything when I speak. 
I want to write a macro saying

```
<Listening>Type {something}</listening>
    <<<< this should fill my TextBox with {Something} >>>>>
```

What extra commands i need to do the same?

and read it back as soon as it has typed.

Thanks

Comment: Hello can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how WSR works, probably it's very simple old HMM approach, but if you really need STT, then either use ready vendor APIs, I made [some comparison here](https://novitoll.blogspot.com/2016/11/preliminary-comparison-of-vendor-sr-apis.html?view=timeslide), or you better use OSS like CMU Sphinx or Kaldi. Depends on your intentions and purpose.